# Opening form in design view on close

Tags: ms-access, vba

I would like to make changes to a form as it is closed. I know I need it in design for to do this, but Access will not allow the form to be in design view "on unload" or "on close." Is there a work around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the design of a form on closing is a very bad idea. Changing the design of a form anytime at runtime is a bad idea. Don't do it. Instead, make the (static) design fit your needs.

Can you explain what you are trying to achieve, rather than your perceived solution.

Comment: I sometimes wish I could hold down the up vote 'til I get bored :)